# Call formsite API from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, api, rest, sql-server-2012

I am trying to call Formsite API from SQL Server to get the data but I am unable to get the data it is returning me null, below is the script which I am using to get the data.

This is my API link (dummy link):

```
https://fs29.formsite.com/api/v2/xyz/forms/form14/
```

Access Token (also dummy):

```
myaccesskey
```

And the script which I am using is

```
DECLARE @authHeader NVARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @contentType NVARCHAR(64);
DECLARE @postData NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @responseText NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @responseXML NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @ret INT;
DECLARE @status NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @statusText NVARCHAR(32);
DECLARE @token INT;
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(256);

-- Set Authentications
SET @authHeader = 'Bearer **mykey**';
SET @contentType = 'application/json';
SET @url = 'https://fs29.formsite.com/api/v2/GwYV/forms/form14/' -- Dummy api url 

EXEC @ret = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @token OUT;

SELECT @token

IF @ret <> 0 
     RAISERROR('Unable to open HTTP connection.', 10, 1);

-- build a request
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @url, 'false';
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Authorization', @authHeader;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-type', @contentType;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Cache-Control', 'no-cache' ;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAMethod @token, 'send'

-- Handle response
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'status', @status OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'statusText', @statusText OUT;
EXEC @ret = sp_OAGetProperty @token, 'responseText', @responseText OUT;

-- Print responses
SELECT @responseText

PRINT 'Status: ' + @status + ' (' + @statusText + ')';
PRINT 'Response text: ' + @responseText;
```

Comment: Don't use this ancient, creaky, error-prone, difficult-to-debug OLE automation approach. Rather, implement it (if you must) using CLR.

Comment: Don't do that! This ancient API is off by default because it's a security nightmare. XMLHTTP  is ancient too, and doesn't support any modern protocol or authentication and authorization method. There's a very good reason you can't make HTTP calls from inside a database. It's a *lot* easier to make such calls from a script, service or application and store the data in the database. All the code you posted is a single `curl` call or `Invoke-WebRequest` in Powershell.

Comment: BTW SQL Server 2012 reached End Of Life in 2018. That's way worse than out-of-support, it means you can't get any fixes/patches anymore unless you specifically pay Microsoft for them. The earliest supported version is SQL Server 2016

Comment: Ole Automation (what OA stands for) isn't available on Linux, so what you try to do won't run if SQL Server is deployed on Linux to save on license costs. Both curl and PowerShell will work though - `curl` started as a Unix tool while Powershell Core is available on Linux